# Reactive forms: Count all formControls in a formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been doing a lot with reactive forms now and really like the concept of it.
However, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to count all formControls in a formGroup, or do I have to iterate over that?

I have a complex nested formGroup structure with 6 or 7 layers, so that would save me a bit time.

Any hint is welcome :)

Comment: what do you mean by 6 or 7 layers? Form Groups nested in FormGroups?

Comment: I've found no quick way. You would need to count the number of nodes in the form object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it recursively.

```
const countControls = (control: AbstractControl): number => {
  if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (control instanceof FormArray) {
    return control.controls.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + countControls(curr), 1)
  }

  if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    return Object.keys(control.controls)
      .map(key => control.controls[key])
      .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + countControls(curr), 1);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  fg: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      two: this.fb.group({
        three: [''],
        four: [''],
        five: [''],
      }),
      six: this.fb.group({
        seven: [''],
        eight: [''],
        nine: this.fb.group({
          ten: [''],
          eleven: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.control(''),
            this.fb.control(''),
            this.fb.control(''),
          ])
        }),
      }),
    });

    // prints 14
    console.log(countControls(this.fg));  
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/recursively-count-form-controls)

Comment: That’s a pretty nice solution, thanks a lot. I’ll check tomorrow and mark it as answer if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @dave0688 got a chance to look at my solution? If so please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Nice solution, thanks a lot! Consider changing the default value of the reduce functions to 0 when you only want to count FormControls. Otherwise it will count one extra for each nested FormGroup or FormArray

Answer (score 11):

The property `controls` of `FormGroup` is an object. To count its keys you could easily do something like:

`Object.keys(yourFormGroup.controls`

If have have more than one `FormGroup` you should anyway iterate over them.